# Freeing memory in QML after loading images

Tags: qt, memory, qml

I'm new in using QtQuick apps, I wanted to ask about memory management, how can I free memory after loading images using Image item using QML ?

Answer (score 1):

Memory management in QML is automatic. You are not supposed to do anything.

However, forcing JavaScript's garbage collection might sometimes help free some memory, as I myself have found the JS engine to be rather liberal with memory usage. You can do that by invoking `gc()`